# Does the usb host device connected to an android phone have to be arduino?

Tags: android, arduino, usb, atmel, accessory

Looking into making a embedded device that uses usb with an android phone and so looking at AOAP and ADK etc and most, if not all, I can find about the embedded devices is in/about Arduino. Does this mean that the embedded device has to be an arduino? Or can another device such as an Atmel board using C be used too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any kind of micro controllers or CPUs as long as it supports Usb or you can use a ftdi adapter to convert from UART or I2C or SPI ..... to USB.
Arduion has an atmel micro controller with the ft232 chip built into it.

Comment: Cool thanks for that! 
You wouldn't happen to know of any resources or guides on implementing usb host on the embedded device would you? Without using arduino. Im trying to use an atmel sam4L8 Xplained Pro